Making a list of swatches with different sizes

Here is how I tentatively coded it despite being utterly wrong (will not run)
Table[Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0,0},{h,h}], {h,0,100,10}}]]

Although asking an exercise question is not a good thing, still for the sake of learning and understanding posting this.

Are the answers to the exercises provided?

No, answers not provided.

The ordering of your ] is wrong. To be precise, the second to last ] is placed too far to the right. Ill let you figure out where to put it.

[FreeformPrompt] Table[Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0,0},{h,h}}], {h,0,100,10}]
Revised. Is the ordering correct now?

I think this exercise in the tutorial is exposing a minor bug in Wolfram Cloud. You are expected to size the swatches, for example using Style.
In Wolfram Cloud, the output is not correct at the first rendering. You have to fiddle around with magnification to get the correct rendering.
Table[Style[Red, s], {s, 10, 100, 10}]



